# Get rest API data and save them into SQL Table with C#

Tags: c#, sql, json, api

Here is what I am looking for. I need to get data from a rest api and insert it into my SQL table.
i have searched here and on google for a solution but they never matched on my needs. Im very new to coding so it is difficult for me to understand all the steps.

Here is what i have so far:

1. I try to call the api (works)
2. to fill the data in a DataTable (NOT WORKING)
3. to insert them in a SQL table

Here my code:

```
protected void btnAPI_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
            ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = (SecurityProtocolType) 3072;

            using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
            {
                client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username,password);
                string json = client.DownloadString("https://XXXX/XXXX001?view=expand");
                JObject jArray = JObject.Parse(json);
                var dt = JsonConvert.DeserializeAnonymousType(json, new { Content = default(DataTable)}).Content; //On this point the code gets an error and it stops


                for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    connection(); //This is my connection string. It works!
                    sqlConn.Open();
                    using (sqlConn)
                    {
                        string qry = "INSERT INTO myTable VALUES(@name, @age, @date)";
                        connection();
                        sqlConn.Open();

                        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(qry, sqlConn))
                        {
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", dt.Rows[i]["name"].ToString());
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@age", dt.Rows[i]["age"].ToString());
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", dt.Rows[i]["date"].ToString());

                            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                        }
                        sqlConn.Close();
                    }
                }
            }
```

Here the json:

```
{
  "@count": 2,
  "@start": 1,
  "@totalcount": 2,
  "Messages": [],
  "ResourceName": "user",
  "ReturnCode": 0,
  "content": [
    {"user": {
      "name": "Eric",
      "age": "25",
      "date": "2021-10-23T11:18:10+00:00",
    }},
    {"user": {
      "name": "Paul",
      "age": "30",
      "date": "2021-10-23T11:18:10+00:00",
    }}]
}
```

Here the error:
`Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: 'Unexpected JSON token when reading DataTable: StartObject. Path 'content[0].user', linke 9, position 20.'`

I think that the issue is that the json im getting has under content a atribute with sub attributes. but i have no idea how i can solve this.

thank you very much for your help.

Regards,
Edi

Comment: The json you have posted is invalid.   Can you post the real json?

Comment: } 
"@count": 2,
  "@start": 1,
  "@totalcount": 2,
  "Messages": [],
  "ResourceName": "user",
  "ReturnCode": 0,
  "content": [
    {"user": {
      "name": Eric,
      "age": "25",
      "date": "2021-10-23T11:18:10+00:00",
    }},
    {"user": {
      "name": Paul,
      "age": "30",
      "date": "2021-10-23T11:18:10+00:00",
    }},
}

Comment: this is what i get when consuming the api

Comment: Your JSON starts with a close brace?  That's invalid json.  Whatever is generating the json is doing a really bad job.  I see sections that end with a comma, which is also invalid.  Ask whoever is creating this json to use a valid JSON generator.  I guess they are trying to do it manually (and failing).

Comment: Sorry about that. there are just copypast mistakes. The should work fine. I just needed to modify the content due to privacy issues. the json should now be good. i updated it

Comment: It's still not good.

Comment: --.-- my bad, again. ] was missing. now json is valid (checked with validator)

Answer (score 1):

First, remove the connection declaration from a loop because your application would suffer a performance degradation from that (maxed out Pool)

Secondly, it is best you cast the response from the API to a object; then it will make your work easier to complete.

Now, the issue could be,

1. the datatype from the API for **name** parameter isn't a string. Therefore you need to align that with the column attribute type
2. Make sure the JSON is properly formatted. It should be string:string
   e.g "name":"stackoverflow"

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will remove the connection out of the loop - thank you

Comment: 1. You're right this should be a bool. i will change it. 
 2. I cannot adjust the JSON. it is a api request i am consuming. 

The issue starts before the code handle the parameter i think.

Comment: Map the json response to an object. You won't get that error or it would be easier to troubleshoot

Comment: Are you familiar with oop?

Comment: Can you how i can map the response to an object? yes but very basic. i created a model for the api but im not sure how the mapping works

Comment: Since you're using webclient, please read through this and let me know if you have further questions

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/consume-webapi-using-webclient-in-c-sharp